# Show $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{a^x}}}{x} = \infty $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Show that for $a > 1$
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{a^x}}}{x} = \infty $$

**I was asked to show it using sequences.**
Hence, We need to show that for every sequcene, $x_n$ diverging to $\infty$, $f(x_n)$ diverging to $\infty$.

If we chose $x_{n_0} = M^M$ then $f(x_{n_0}) = a^M > M$ (because $a>1$).

But that would work if I showed $f(x)$ is monotonly increasing which I'm struggling to show. Maybe that's not the right way.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

For some $x \ge N \in \Bbb N , a^x > x^2, \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a^x}{x} > \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x} = \dots $

Comment: That's nice. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome AnnieOK :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest analyzing it this way.

Let a$_n$=$\frac{a^n}{n}$. This means that a$_{n+1}$=$\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Analyzing the ratio between two following terms of the sequence, we find that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$=$\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$$\frac{n}{a^n}$=$\frac{a}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$.

The limit of the ratio of the succession clearly goes to $a$, so the succession is, at least from a certain point, monotonic. From the previous formula, we can also see that $a_{n+1}=a_n\frac{a}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ .

If the sequence had $l$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as a limit, both $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ would have l as a limit, so  we could see that $l=al$. Since the function is definitively monotonic, and the limit cannot be zero, this would imply that $a=1$, which is absurd. This conclusion came from the wrong supposition that $l$ is finite. Since the sequence is definitively monotonic, the limit is $+\infty$.